# Unable to start NTP

Tags: ntp

Last week it works correctly, but now, my virtual machine inside virtualbox out of sync by 5 minutes

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-09-30 18:52:31 WIB; 10s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 25684 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Idle."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─25684 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

$ timedatectl set-ntp true 

$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Wed 2015-09-30 18:54:17 WIB
  Universal time: Wed 2015-09-30 11:54:17 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2015-09-30 11:46:27
       Time zone: Asia/Jakarta (WIB, +0700)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no

$ cat /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf

[Time]
NTP=0.asia.pool.ntp.org,1.asia.pool.ntp.org,2.asia.pool.ntp.org,3.asia.pool.ntp.org
FallbackNTP=0.arch.pool.ntp.org 1.arch.pool.ntp.org 2.arch.pool.ntp.org 3.arch.pool.ntp.org
```

what's the cause of `NTP synchronized: no`?

I'm using 64-bit ArchLinux and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd

**EDIT** ah it works now

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
$ systemctl restart ntpd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
$ systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
$ systemctl restart ntpd
$ timedatectl status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      Local time: Wed 2015-09-30 18:56:49 WIB
  Universal time: Wed 2015-09-30 11:56:49 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2015-09-30 11:56:49
       Time zone: Asia/Jakarta (WIB, +0700)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run a full ntp server on a virtual machine. ntp and virtual machines do not play well together as the emulated clock violates the assumptions made by ntp. Instead run ntp on the host and sntp on the virtual machines to synchronize to the host. This is not quite as accurate but does not have the sync issues of running ntp on a virtual machine.